# firefox proxy settings through terminal in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: shell

I switch from one proxy to another very frequently and needs to change my proxy settings of my browser very frequently. I am attempting to  write a script  file that changes proxy of firefox according to that value that i pass to the script. I went through the posts in stackoverflow but nothing seems to be very relevant to what i need.

Comment: Have you seen Foxy Proxy? http://getfoxyproxy.org/

Answer (score 1):

I have a script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` which determines which proxy to use for the current connections and then calls:

```
gconf --type string --set /system/proxy/mode "manual"
gconf --type bool --set /system/http_proxy/use_http_proxy "true"
gconf --type string --set /system/http_proxy/host $PROXY_HOST
gconf --type int --set /system/http_proxy/port $PROXY_PORT
gconf --type bool --set /system/http_proxy/use_same_proxy "true"  
gconf --type bool --set /system/http_proxy/use_authentication $AUTH_REQUIRED
gconf --type string --set /system/http_proxy/authentication_user $DOMAIN_USER
gconf --type string --set /system/http_proxy/authentication_password $DOMAIN_PWD
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Why not you set firefox to use System Proxy setting.
2. Write script to change the proxy setting in your profile.